# Flutter смахивание виджета с экрана

Tags: android, flutter, dart, material-design, material-ui

Доброго времени суток.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы виджет следовал за движением свайпа, а когда свайп завершиться, то я мог выполнить `setState`, чтобы скрыть виджет из дерева?

Я пытался сделать следующим образом, через `GestureDetector` по событию `onVerticalDragEnd` менял состояние и виджет скрывался, но мне нужно, чтобы виджет, пока пользователь продолжает движение пальца следовал за ним, то есть, добавить отзывчивость эдакую.

Попробовал сделать через событие `onVerticalDragUpdate`, достаю из него `delta` смещение и к элементу positioned добавляю это смещение в top параметр. Теперь работает следование за пальцем, но не работает событие `onVerticalDragEnd`.

Пытался использовать `Draggable`, но, как я понял, он тоже в этой ситуации не работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать такое окошко?

Код этого кусочка:

```
// Модальное окно (панелька) выбора
          if (_isChoiceModalOpen)
            Positioned(
              top: _modalTopOffset,
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: AppDrawerChoiceModalView(),
                onVerticalDragEnd: (_) => setState(() {
                  _isChoiceModalOpen = false;
                }),
                onVerticalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) => setState((){
                  _modalTopOffset += details.delta.dy;
                }),
              ),
            ),
```

Оно лежит внутри Stack'а, поэтому Positioned работает.

Полный код с родительским виджетом:

```
class _AppDrawerViewState extends State<AppDrawerView> {

  late bool _isChoiceModalOpen;
  late double _modalTopOffset;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _isChoiceModalOpen = false;
    _modalTopOffset = 0.0;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final EdgeInsets notchInset = MediaQuery.of(context).padding;
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Drawer(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: AppColors.secondaryBackground,
            child: ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Image.asset("assets/screens/main/images/avatar.png"),
                  onTap: () => setState(() {
                    _isChoiceModalOpen = true;
                  }),
                ),
                Divider(
                  height: 3,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                // Главная
                AppDrawerTileView(
                  icon: Icons.home_outlined,
                ),
                // Новости
                AppDrawerTileView(
                    icon: Icons.article_outlined,
                ),
                // Выход
                AppDrawerTileView(
                    icon: Icons.logout_outlined,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          // Модальное окно (панелька) выбора
          if (_isChoiceModalOpen)
            Positioned(
              top: _modalTopOffset,
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: AppDrawerChoiceModalView(),
                onVerticalDragEnd: (_) => setState(() {
                  _isChoiceModalOpen = false;
                }),
                onVerticalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) => setState((){
                  _modalTopOffset += details.delta.dy;
                }),
              ),
            ),
        ]
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Лишние элементы, виджеты и т.п. убрал, чтобы была понятна суть и  не было совсем неразборчиво большого кода.

Здесь происходит следующее. При инициализации менюшки, модальное окно закрыто и отступ равен нулю. По нажатию на аватарке в шапке меню открывается модальное окошко.

```
GestureDetector(
                  child: Image.asset("assets/screens/main/images/avatar.png"),
                  onTap: () => setState(() {
                    _isChoiceModalOpen = true;
                  }),
                ),
```

Нужно сделать возможность его смахивать.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёлся виджет для решения этой проблемы. `Dismissible` с параметром `direction: DismissDirection.down`